# TCP socket BeginReceive giving me in-order socket data out of order

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I'm communicating with a serial port on a terminal server, so in-order guarantee is important. According to Wireshark the packets are coming in in order. The Sequences are also fine.

But my buffer that I write to with the Async Callback is sometimes, not always, receiving packet data out of order. I thought TCP guaranteed in order reception of data?

In the code below, at the very bottom, it's the InputBuffer that gets the data out of order sometimes. What's going on?

```
private void WaitForData()
{
    try
    {
         if (moCallBack == null)
         {
             moCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
         }
         SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
         theSocPkt.thisSocket = moClientSocket;
         moResult = moClientSocket.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer,
                    0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                    SocketFlags.None,
                    moCallBack,
                    theSocPkt);
}
private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    try
    {
        //Set up socket data
        SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
        int iRx = socketData.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
        if (iRx > 0 && this.modemState.State != MODEM_CONN_STATE.DISCONNECTED)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[iRx];
            bytes = socketData.dataBuffer;
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref bytes, iRx);
            this.HayesBuff.AddRange(bytes);
            modemConnSMachine();
            WaitForData();
        }
    }
}

private void modemConnSMachine()
{
    switch (modemState.State)
    {
        case MODEM_CONN_STATE.CONNECTED:
             switch(chkModResp(this.HayesBuff))
             {
                 case MODEM_RESPONSE.DATA:
                      signConnectionTimeoutTimer.Change(noChatsTimeoutSec, noChatsTimeoutSec);
                      lock (this.InputBuffer)
                      {
                          this.InputBuffer.AddRange(this.HayesBuff);
                          this.HayesBuff.RemoveRange(0, HayesBuff.Count);
                      }
                      break;
```

Comment: also, no ZoneAlarm or other firewall installed here.

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick, but I just wanted to point out that there's no point in doing `bytes = new byte[iRx];` if you're going to do `bytes = socketData.dataBuffer;` immediately afterward.

Comment: How is your `SocketPacket` class obtaining its `Socket` object for the `thisSocket` field in the `WaitForData` method? Are you keeping your `Socket` object as a static reference somewhere? Is the `SocketPacket` class creating a new `Socket` object?

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice-- WaitForData creates a new one. Inside WaitForData:
SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
theSocPkt.thisSocket = moClientSocket;
moResult = moClientSocket.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer,0,theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,moCallBack,theSocPkt);